# Let $f,g,h$ functions, how to prove or refute if $f=g$ then $h\circ f=h\circ g$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

First, i define the sets of the functions $f:A \rightarrow B,g:A \rightarrow B, h:B \rightarrow C $.

Let $z \in C$, by the definition of the function $(h\circ f)$, $\exists x;$

$z=(h\circ f)(x)\implies z=h(f(x))\implies z=h(g(x)) \implies z=(h\circ g)(x)$

Then $(h\circ f)=(h\circ g)$.

Is my show okay?

Comment: Why start at $z\in C$? Better say, let $x\in A$. Then show that $$(h\circ f)(x)=(h\circ g)(x).$$

Comment: If f=g ,  h o f is   h  o    g   .

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just about right, except you should instead show this statement for all $x$. I.e. $\forall x\in A$
$$ (h\circ f)(x)=h(f(x))=h(g(x))=(h\circ g)(x)$$
so, $h\circ f=h\circ g$ as functions. Also, you should be careful: there does not necessarily exist an $x$ such that $(h\circ f)(x)=z$, because we don't know that $h\circ f$ is surjective. Instead, for all $x$, there exists a $z$ such that $z=(h\circ f)(x)$.

Answer (score -1):

This implication does not need any such proof.  It is an instance of one of the [axioms of equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms): $$u=v\implies F(u)=F(v)$$ for any function $F$. Actually, you did use this axiom when writing (under the hypothesis $f=g$): "$z=h(f(x))\implies z=h(g(x))$".

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something I can improve?